# Create list in one function, then use it in another in python (pythonista ios)

Tags: python, ios, list, user-interface, pythonista

Would be very appreciative of some help. Specifically, I'm using the UI module in pythonista, along with a .pyui file.

My application has two buttons - one called 'compile' and another called 'execute'.

Compile:

```
# First Button
def compile(sender):
    *creates a list by calling another function*
    *let's say this is called "myList"*
```

Execute:

```
# Second button that pulls a random element from the list
def execute(sender):
    random.choice(myList)
```

However, it appears that while I create myList in button 1 (and it works fine), I can't call upon it in button2, as they are two separate instances.

Therefore, is there a way to make the list 'global' in some way? What's the best and most pythonic solution here?

Answer (score 4):

just declare list outside of functions

```
my_list = []

def fun1():
    *do smth with my_list*

def fun2():
    *do smth with my_list too*
```

Comment: Well, that was simple. Thank you!